# add an Image as a footer by iText

Tags: java, itext

I want to add a footer to my pdf document but the code bellow dosen't work, please don't consider this question as duplicate ... This code is the same in the answer of a similar question;

```
protected void buildPdfDocument(Map model, Document document,
        PdfWriter writer, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        response.setCharacterEncoding("application/pdf;charset=UTF-8");
        document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());

        Image imf= Image.getInstance("D:\\footer.png");
        imf.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
        imf.scaleAbsoluteHeight(20);
        imf.scaleAbsoluteWidth(20);
        imf.scalePercent(100);

        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(imf, 0, -45);
        HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(chunk), false);
        footer.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        footer.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        document.setFooter(footer);

        document.open();
        document.newPage();

             // add tables and other elements 

        document.close();



    }
```

then after executing the code, the image is not showing up .. I'm using iText v2.1.7.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move code where you set footer after `document.newPage();`